# Threejs - i cant load material from JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

hi i have a simple TheeJS code which i want to load some 3D js files using JSONLoader in it.
the 3D files were exported from blender exporter and when i run this part of code it get me two errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined
```

and this is a little part of my code which is going to load the json 3D file:

```
var load = function ( file, callback )
{
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( file, function( geometry, materials ){
        callback( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ) ) );
    });
}

load("models/porsche.js", function(car){
    car.position.set( 0, 0, -2 );
    car.rotation.y = Math.PI / -2;
    scene.add(car);
});
```

Also when i use other kinds of Materials for example phong or lambert it works very well but it gave these errors when i use MeshFaceMaterial
What Should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is in the json file, check if the pataramer shading  is correct in the material. Some as "shading" :"Lambert".